Cannot manually populate my sqflite database in Flutter app
So these are my data classes
class Category {
  final int? id;
  final String name;
  final String thumbnail;

  Category({this.id, required this.name, required this.thumbnail});

  // Convert a Category into map
  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    return {
      'id': id,
      'name': name,
      'thumbnail': thumbnail,
    };
  }

  // Extract
  factory Category.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    return Category(
      id: map['id'],
      name: map['name'],
      thumbnail: map['thumbnail'],
    );
  }
}
class SvgFile {
  final int? id;
  final int categoryId;
  final String filePath;
  final String name; // New field for the name of the SVG file

  SvgFile({this.id, required this.categoryId, required this.filePath, required this.name});

  // Convert SvgFile into map
  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    return {
      'id': id,
      'category_id': categoryId,
      'file_path': filePath,
      'name': name, // Include the name in the map
    };
  }

  // Extract SvgFile from map
  factory SvgFile.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    return SvgFile(
      id: map['id'],
      categoryId: map['category_id'],
      filePath: map['file_path'],
      name: map['name'], // Retrieve the name from the map
    );
  }
}


Then i have this to manually input data into the sqlite database, i have a db helper as well:
class DataPopulator {
  final DatabaseHelper dbHelper = DatabaseHelper.instance;

  Future<void> populateData() async {
    // List of categories and their associated SVG files with names
    final List<Map<String, dynamic>> categoriesWithSvgFiles = [
      {
        'name': 'Animals',
        'thumbnail': 'assets/images/animal.png',
        'svgs': [
          {'filePath': 'assets/images/animal/weird_animal.svg', 'name': 'Weird Animal'},
          {'filePath': 'assets/images/animal/deer.svg', 'name': 'Deer'},
          {'filePath': 'assets/images/animal/dino.svg', 'name': 'Dinosaur'},
          
        ],
      },
      
    ];

    Future<void> populateData() async {
      for (var categoryMap in categoriesWithSvgFiles) {
        // Insert category and get the id
        int categoryId = await dbHelper.insertCategory(Category(
          name: categoryMap['name'],
          thumbnail: categoryMap['thumbnail'],
        ));

        // Insert associated SVG files
        for (var svg in categoryMap['svgs']) {
          await dbHelper.insertSvgFile(SvgFile(
            categoryId: categoryId,
            filePath: svg['filePath'],
            name: svg['name'],
          ));
        }
      }
    }


    // Insert data into the database
    for (var categoryData in categoriesWithSvgFiles) {
      // Create a Category object
      Category category = Category(
        name: categoryData['name'],
        thumbnail: categoryData['thumbnail'],
      );

      // Insert the category into the database
      int categoryId = await dbHelper.insertCategory(category);

      // Insert associated SVG files into the database
      for (var svgFileData in categoryData['svgs']) {
        SvgFile svgFile = SvgFile(
          categoryId: categoryId,
          filePath: svgFileData['filePath'],
          name: svgFileData['name'],
        );

        await dbHelper.insertSvgFile(svgFile);
      }
    }

    print("Data population complete");//debug
  }
}

void main() async {
  DataPopulator dataPopulator = DataPopulator();
  await dataPopulator.populateData();
}

When i run my app, it keeps saying "No categories found"
My app has multiple categories, and each category has a list of svgfiles, I want to manually populate the database before opening the application.
this is my main
void main() {
  // Initialize the database factory
  databaseFactory = databaseFactoryFfi; // Set the database factory
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Category Navigation',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.green,
      ),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,

      initialRoute: '/',
      routes: {
        '/': (context) => HomePage(),
        '/see_all_categories': (context) => SeeAllCategoriesPage(),
      },
    );
  }
}

